# Indexed array in query

Tags: openapi, swagger-php

I am struggling to write a parameter annotation for a field that would have to result as indexed array of integers:

```
voucher_products[0]: 23
voucher_products[1]: 102
voucher_products[2]: 233
```

I tried the following

```
 *     @OA\Parameter(
 *         name="voucher_products",
 *         in="query",
 *         description="",
 *         required=false,
 *         @OA\Schema(
 *             type="array",
 *               @OA\Items(
 *                 type="integer",
 *               )
 *         )
 *     ),
```

I complete the form this way:
[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkOIb.png)

The result I get in the query string parameters is

```
voucher_products: 23
voucher_products: 102
voucher_products: 233
```

If I check this field in $_POST its final value is `voucher_products=233`, since this doesn't turn to be an array.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenAPI Specification curently doesn't have a way to represent query strings containing an indexed array such as

```
?arr[0]=val1&arr[1]=val2&arr[2]=val3&...
```

Here's are the related issues in the OpenAPI Specification repository:
[Are indexes in the query parameter array representable?](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1501)
[Support deep objects for query parameters with deepObject style](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1706)

However, if your API can accept the array with just square brackets but without the indexes

```
?voucher_products[]=23&voucher_products[]=102&voucher_products[]=233
```

then you can define it as a parameter with `name="voucher_products[]"`.